# Proxy Proxy for Windows XP (like Authoxy for Mac)

Tags: proxy, authentication

On my Mac I use [Authoxy](http://www.hrsoftworks.net/Products.php#authoxy) to avoid having to continuously reauthenticate to my client's proxy server. It works like this: I give Authoxy my credentials and the location of the PAC file. It runs locally on some port (say 8888) and any program where I need to specify a proxy server, I put 127.0.0.1:8888. The program connects to Authoxy and it connects to the real proxy server. I don't have to copy authentication info everywhere, reenter credentials all the time, etc. Very nice. More importantly, apps that are too stupid to support proxy authentication or that don't support PAC files can connect to Authoxy, whereas I'm screwed with the normal proxy.

I need someway to accomplish the same thing in Windows XP.

Comment: To me, this sounds more http://superuser.com a-like

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project).  It's Java based, has a Java Web Start installer or a JAR executable, whichever.  All kinds of fun toys there.

**EDIT:** ooh, wait.  Might not support autoproxy config yet...  Thought that it did.  Still is an awesome tool, though!

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/), this does what you are looking for if your upstream proxy is MS ISA.

Comment: While there's a lot of indications that this works for most people; I had the hardest time making this work in a EDS supported corporate network. Something about the certificate signing and using a non-standard root certificate verification service.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-free tool that looks like it does what I need: http://www.proxifier.com/

Still holding out for a free version though. Anyone?